# How to count distinct column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me ..

I run this query :

```
select 
    distinct barang, COUNT(*) as jumlah, CAST(COUNT(*) as float) / 6 
from  
    tbltes  
group by 
    barang 
Having 
    CAST(COUNT(*) as float) / 6 >0.2
```

and now.. I want to count all row that showed by the query above..

I had tried this query ..

```
 select 
     count (distinct barang)    
 from 
     tbltes 
 group by 
     barang  
 having 
     CAST(COUNT(*) as float) /6 > 0.2
```

but not like what I expected...

So I need your help master...

Comment: Can you explain why it is not what you expected with an example?

Comment: Do you want the number of rows in database table tbltes used to create the results ? or the number of rows in results ?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?: `HAVING CAST(COUNT(*) as float) / 6 >0.2` Why not `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your existing query as a sub-query. By the way, there is no need for `select distinct` if yo have a `group by` clause.

```
select count(distinct sq.barang)
from
(
select  barang as barang
        ,COUNT(*) as jumlah
from    tbltes  
group by 
        barang 
) sq
where cast(sq.jumlah as float)/6 > 0.2
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb2cf/13)

Comment: i had tried your query but it doesn't work
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: OK, I've revised the SQL. Take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the number of rows in database table tbltes used to create the results ? or the number of rows in results ?

If the latter just put `Select Count(*) From` around the whole thing...

```
 Select Count(*)
 From  (select distinct barang,COUNT(*) as jumlah,
            CAST(COUNT(*) as float) / 6 
        from  tbltes  
        group by barang 
        Having CAST(COUNT(*) as float) / 6 >0.2 ) z
```

Comment: i want the number of rows in results .
i had tried your query but it doesn't work
 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.